# What criteria would you assess to gauge whether to quit a Ph.D for a job in industry?

Tags: phd, quitting

Just started my second year of a 3.5 year EPSRC funded Ph.D (in engineering, and using some machine learning) in the UK. I have recently finished my confirmation review so have secured the funding for the remainder of the Ph.D.

I have a conference paper from my first year, but I have spent most of the year up and down with the ebbs and flows of research and I am not sure I can handle it mentally anymore.

I am looking at applying for data science/analyst positions. I think I am far better suited to a life in industry.

Part of me thinks I should just try and grind it out and finish (maybe this is second year blues?), but part of me also just wants to get out and start progressing with my career (I already have a Masters degree).

At what stage would you consider leaving a PhD in order to pursue an industry career?

Comment: The question is personal and opinion based, so not a good candidate for this site. I suggest you seek local advice from people who know you.

Comment: Fair enough. Though perhaps it would be good to hear of any people who felt this way during their and what they chose to do?

Comment: Sure this is okay (why wouldn't it be?). If your fear is that industry sees you as a failure when not completing the PHD, you might want to apply and leave the PHD program as soon as you find an industry job. Don't waste time in academia if it makes you unhappy.

Comment: Yes, it is the fear of being seen as a failure by industry and the potential damage it may have to career prospects. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Be sure it's not just post-conference-depression. Everybody goes through these ups-and-downs. Put the question aside for at least three days. Don't brood on it. Find useful activity. "If you feel bad, act" is a wise proverb.  If you feel bad for weeks then something needs to change.

Comment: I'd like to share my experience. I did a PhD on Computer Vision that took 4 years. I suffered from the impostor syndrome a lot and stopped to think about quitting at least once every year. Some time after I completed it, I was asked if I would apply for a PhD again if we were back in time. After thinking a lot, I said "no".

Today, 6 years later, I think the opposite. Although I don't think my PhD thesis was great, it produced some results that are highly valued by some people in the community. Also, having a PhD opened the door to very good jobs in the industry, where I am now.

Comment: Can you switch to an MPhil?

Comment: I think I can switch to an MPhil. My research interests are based more in the machine learning side of things instead of the structural engineering aspects.

Answer (score 7):

"you think" you'd be happy working might not be enough, depend on the situation I suggest you to take a leave of absence (usually universities in the UK allow this) for 6-12 months, and get a job so you know for sure what ticks for you, then decide whether to return to your program or keep the industry position. Don't feel guilty for taking options that are readily available.

I had similar experience and this, to go or to stay, might be the hardest question I had to answer myself for the longest time. In the end I decided to stick it out, but I also have a close friend who's having the time of their live ditching their PhD 2 years in. You just need to work out the best approach for your situation, and the best way to do it is from a little bit of distance.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

The standard advice given on the Workplace StackExchange site is “don’t quit your job until you get an offer from another employer”. I think that would also apply to your case: don’t quit your PhD until you’ve gotten a job offer from someone in industry. You may or may not regret quitting your PhD for a job in industry, but you’ll definitely regret quitting your PhD and then *failing* to find a job in industry!